# Programmatically changing button shadows is working for all but the first row, yet the first row's background is indeed changing?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 4 stackViews, each containing a set of buttons for a custom keyboard. I have a function that edits their appearance. I have added a shadow offset:

```
            btn.layer.shadowRadius = 0.5
            btn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
            btn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.5)
```

I'm setting the button background's to white, and changing the font color. it works for ALL of them. However, the shadow/opacity is only working for the last 3 rows... but I tried changing the "Q" to "F" to make sure that that btn is being iterated over, which it definitely is as you can see in the picture:

[image]

here's the full function:

```
func setButtonUI (containerView: UIStackView) {     
    for view in containerView.subviews {
        if let btn = view as? UIButton {
            btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            btn.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue: 102.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
            btn.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

            //shadows (working for all but first row)
            btn.layer.shadowRadius = 0.5
            btn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
            btn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.5)

            if btn.currentTitle == "Q" {
                btn.setTitle("F", for: .normal)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

any ideas as to why the first row is not getting the shadow effects?

Comment: Yes, have just tested on device and same problem.

Comment: have you tried setting the view.layer.maskToBounds = false as well as view.clipsToBounds = false in your iteration?